# Smoke from motherboard caused by probable faulty fans

Tags: motherboard, fan

Pc builders,

You hope to never experience it but I've had some smoke coming of my motherboard after putting it into a new case(Silverstone PS15 RGB). I'm really sure about the cause; the included rgb fans.

The fans come with two connectors, one for power and one for 12v rgb leds. You can chain the 12v led connectors and then connect it to the mobo but for somehow it sets the fans to  100% RPM when both are powered.. When you only connect one fan by 12v the RPM suddenly becomes controllable by voltage via the mobo. Really weird.. The power connectors are just regular 3 pin sys fan. Therefore I decided to use a small controller from my old case(fractal design node 304) with a switch for three presets of fan speeds. You can plug in both the fan power connectors and then power the hub with a molex from the PSU. See this link for the  controller:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4p2mQ.jpg

After doing so and testing it out by playing with the presets, some smoke comes off the bottom left of the motherboard(Gigabyte Z370N WIFI). This happened twice till I figured out that the controller was causing a short. After removing the controller everything seemed to be still functional. I've ran some long stress tests on the GPU an cpu and had zero crashes. However during gaming it can work for a day and then the next day I get a crashes. Black screen, audio lagg and eventually a lost connection to the display. When looking up the crash, via reliability overview in windows, it says it's an error code 116 related to the graphics card. I've done a small overclock but that worked fine before new case. Fortunately the GPU( 5600XT) wasn't connected when the short was caused.

I'm really concerned about what parts could be broken aside from the GPU. I think if I apply for a RMA for the motherboard I will be fine, however I read that other parts, like the PSU could also be damaged. Im also curious about my "rights" because of the faulty fans from Silverstone that caused this. Aside from the 12v led connector the fans weren't even powered by the motherboard, how can this be possible?

So lots of questions, hope to get some advice from you guys!

Comment: "I figured out that the controller was causing a short." So regardless of whether the fans were faulty you added your own hardware that caused the damage ...

Comment: Once you let the magic smoke out, I'd forget about any idea of being able to RMA it. It was your responsibility to test for compatibility.

Comment: Well yeah i agree with the both of you, but still it's a controller that worked for year with two other fans. On behalf of Silverstone i find it odd that this can happen.